# DJANGO ошибка ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bboard'

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Учу *Django* по книге. при запуске выдает ошибку. В чем ошибка?

ОШИБКА:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bboard'

Код в settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'bboard.apps.BboardConfig',
       ]
```

Код в views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Здесь будет список объявлений")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1):

А это нормально, что у вас в **INSTALLED_APPS** *b* написано два раза?
Я думаю, эту проблему можно решить так:

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'board.apps.BboardConfig',
]
```

Если же и это не поможет - воспользуйтесь этим кодом:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'board.apps.BoardConfig',
]
```

Comment: Мой ответ помог?

Comment: Привет, нет ошибка не в этом, в книге написано написать два раза b, так что не работает(

Comment: @tverniy а вы хоть это приложение установили?(я про bboard)

Comment: да, через команду manage.py startapp bboard